# Ajax load via jquery, content not shown

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

hi i have a html file which use ajax for loading contents from other html files in the same server. for some reason it does not work?? i have no clue as i am new to ajax.

**here is the index.html(default home page)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head><body><div id="rounded">
<img src="img/top_bg.gif" alt="top" /><div id="main" class="container">
<h1>ajax example</h1>
<h2>ajax jquery</h2>
<ul id="navigation">
<li><a href="#info">Page_1</a></li>
<li><a href="#page2">Page2</a></li>
<li><a href="#page3">Page_3</a></li>
<li><a href="#page4">Page_4</a></li>
<li><img id="loading" src="img/ajax_load.gif" alt="loading" /></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="pageContent">
it is a test</div>
</div><div class="clear"></div>
<img src="img/bottom_bg.gif" alt="bottom" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js(for adding hash in the url and enable back button and also loading content)**

```
ar default_content = "";
$(document).ready(function () {
    checkURL();
    $('ul li a').click(function (e) {
        checkURL(this.hash);
    });
    default_content = $('#pageContent').html();
    setInterval("checkURL()", 250);
});
var lasturl = "";

function checkURL(hash) {
    if (!hash) hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash != lasturl) {
        lasturl = hash;
        if (hash == "")
            $('#pageContent').html(default_content);
        else
            loadPage(hash);
    }
}

function loadPage(url) {
    var datastring = url.replace('#', '');
    $('#loading').css('visibility', 'visible');
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'datastring=' + datastring,
        dataType: "html",
        async: false,
        success: function (msg) {
            if (parseInt(msg) != 0) {
                $('#content').html(msg);
                $('#loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

**and load_page.php**

```
<?php  
$url = $_REQUEST['datastring'];
echo $url;

if(file_exists(''.$url.'.html')){
echo file_get_contents(''.$url.'.html');
}
else{ 
echo 'There is no such page!';
}
?>
```

need help! as you can see when the ajax calls the "pagecontent" div loads the content from the requested page, but nothing happens here! what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Few tips for getting an answer fast:
a) format your code
b) keep it simple
c) provide a jsfiddle
d) provide all the necessary materials

Comment: Have you viewed the XHR in developer tool on the network tab? Have you checked any jquery errors on the console?

Comment: @Anagio yup i checked the XHR and when i click on the line (eg. page_1) it actually request the page. under the XHR tab, there is response tab and i can see the requested content in there but it does not show in the index page.

Comment: View the source in developer tool and search the source in developer tool do you see it?

Comment: well never mind that, i entered wrong div class, thats why the data never shows. but now i have a new problem, when the data loads it shows the page name before the content,(eg. if i requested for a page named info, the content i get is "infoheregoes the content......."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have "#content' in the ajax response handler... should be '#pageContent' to match the div id.  That is:

```
success: function (msg) {
    if (parseInt(msg) != 0) {
        $('#pageContent').html(msg);
        $('#loading').css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
}
```

Comment: @Avik if it worked you should also hit the check mark to set it as the correct answer.